# Windows10でexeファイルを実行したら、エラー：Access violation at address

Tags: c#, delphi, rad-studio

Windows10で'xxxxxx.exe'を実行したら、下記エラーが表示され処理ができません。

```
Access violation at address 0066472F in module 'xxxxxx.exe'.Read of addres 0000007C.
```

上記エラーが発生した場合の確認方法や確認手段、疑うべき部分、手順などを教えて下さい。

使用言語：Delphi+C#
IDE:Rad Studio10.2で構築されたプロジェクトを10.4に移行して開発

＜エラーの発生個所と思われる部分＞
メインモジュールの表示処理で、「メインモジュールのuses句で結合している『インストール済設計時パッケージ』」の一部がnilになり、nilになった結果、nil部品の内部プロパティをセットしようとし、「Access violation」が出力されているところまで分かったが、
・問題のある設計時パッケージはRad Studio10.4で正常インストールされており、「設計時パッケージ一覧に表示されている」
・問題のあるパッケージを直接プロジェクトファイルをRad Studio10.4で開いてクリーンアップ＆ビルド正常終了
・Rad Studio10.4でデバッグ実行時に、「Access violation」エラー発生
・Rad Studio10.4でビルドしたモジュールexeを起動させた場合も、「読み取り違反」エラーが発生

<今まで確認したこと・試行したこと>
・今回の問題の発生直前で変更したポイントは「Rad Studioを10.2⇒10.4に変更」(ビルド端末には.NET3.5.2と4系では.NET4.6までが導入されいてる)
・「Access violation」エラーが発生した際、デバッガでコンポーネントの追加をモジュール画面から行ったが「読み込めなかった」
・当該モジュールのコンパイル指定はRad Studio2007のコンパイルバージョンが最高値(VCL4)だった。Rad Studio10.4で再ビルドしたがエラー解消せず。
・今回の問題の発生直前で変更したポイントは「Rad Studioを10.2⇒10.4に変更」(ビルド端末には.NET3.5.2と4系では.NET4.6までが導入されいてる)
・「Access violation」エラーが発生した際、デバッガでコンポーネントの追加をモジュール画面から行ったが「読み込めなかった」
・当該モジュールのコンパイル指定はRad Studio2007のコンパイルバージョンが最高値(VCL4)だった。Rad Studio10.4で再ビルドしたがエラー解消せず。
・OracleクライアントのDLLなど他のモジュールは読み込めている。
・データベースアクセスを行うpasモジュールをデザイナで開こうとすると『TQueryがない』旨の、Rad Studioのエラーポップアップ表示
・問題が起きているモジュールはRad Studio10.2、.NET3.5では「ビルド後のモジュールで起動、動作できていた」
・Rad Studio10.4にバージョンアップ、設計時パッケージ一覧をエンバカデロ提供「移行ツール」で移行した。
・問題発生後、「設計時パッケージ一覧」から項目削除、当該モジュールをクリーンアップ＆ビルド後にパッケージのインストールで正常登録を確認。
・クリーンアップ＆ビルド後に再度デバッガで起動確認を行ったところ、当該モジュールのインスタンスをセットしているタイミングで、セットの元の中身がnilだった。

Comment: なお、Rad Studio10.2で動作していた.NET Frameworkは3.5です。同端末にRad Studio10.4と.NET Frameworkは4.6を追加導入して、動作させようとしています。

Comment: この辺の記事が何か参考になるかもしれません。[\[delphi-users:2266\] アドレス違反でエラーのソース位置を知る方法](https://groups.google.com/g/delphi-users/c/tZIhbeWox4c), [How to track down access violation "at address 00000000"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2237028/9014308), [Access Violation - Execution of Address](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35262927/9014308), [Why small changes make "Access violation at address xxx" error on this delphi code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20124011/9014308), [Delphi, error :"Access violation at address xxxxxxxx. Read of address yyyyyyyy", ...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20048406/9014308)

Comment: @kunif

コメントありがとうございます。   
頂いた記事の詳細確認を行っておりますが、こちらでの試行内容も併せて記載したいと思います。(長くてすみません)

Comment: @kunif アドバイスありがとうございます。助かります。

Comment: 他にこんな記事も。[Debugging Access Violation errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6214458/9014308), [Access violation at address 00822135 in module 'GUI.exe'.Read of address 00000040 \[closed\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14030815/9014308), [Memory Access Violation from a Delphi written DLL. Trying to access through DLLImport](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70268931/9014308) それから私はDelphiの経験は無いので検索して紹介するくらいですが、知っている人向けにはこちらのヘルプ記事を参考に質問内容を改善してみてください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: マルチポスト⇒ https://teratail.com/questions/374475

Answer (score 1):

BDEでデータベース接続をするアプリケーションなのですね？TQueryはBDEのコンポーネントなのですが、IDEのデザイナで開けないということは、BDEがインストールされていないものと思われます。
BDEはエンバカデロのポータルサイト https://my.embarcadero.com/ からダウンロードできます(BDE for RAD Studio 10.4)ので、こちらをインストールしてみてください。

Comment: 補足です。
> 上記エラーが発生した場合の確認方法や確認手段、疑うべき部分、手順などを教えて下さい。
今回のポイントは
> データベースアクセスを行うpasモジュールをデザイナで開こうとすると『TQueryがない』旨の、Rad Studioのエラーポップアップ表示
で、デザイナ画面で表示できないということは、そのコンポーネントを乗せたコンテナ(フォーム、データモジュール)を実行時に生成しようとしたときも同様にエラーになり、コンテナ上のコンポーネントが生成されずにnilになり、これが原因でAVとなる、というところです。

Comment: アドバイス・ご説明、とても理解しやすかったです。ありがとうございます。
エラー発生しているビルド端末にて、BDEをインストール後、「dclbde270.bpl」をRad Studio10.4でパッケージのインストール実施。
　⇒　結果、当該プロシージャはnilのままで、AVエラー発生。
　⇒⇒　ストアド作成の際のDB側のユーザ権限とも考え、一度、プロシージャをDROP後、ユーザを変更して、再度CREATEしたが、実行時の状況はnilのまま変わらずエラーが発生しました。

Comment: BDEをインストールしたら、まずはIDEですべてのフォーム、データモジュールを開いて、エラーが出ないことを確認してみてください。

Comment: ご助言ありがとうございます。一度すべてのプロジェクト内のpasファイルをデザイナでオープンし、DBモジュールも含めて、コンポーネント類が画面の構成部品として登録されていること、エラーが発生していないことが確認できました。